# Using bastionssh with config file

Tags: bastion

I am attempting to use bastionssh to access a number of other servers. My point of contact is a colleague who is based on the other side of the world so getting information can be tricky. He provided me with access for the bastionssh server and provided me with a config file with details such as those below:

```
Host hostname
User username
TCPKeepAlive yes
HostName x.x.x.x
ProxyCommand ssh bastionssh nc %h %p
```

I am not sure how to attempt a connection to this host. I had tried

```
ssh bastionssh nc %h %p
```

But got permission denied. Didn't expect it to work and fear it may be a false identification of permissions mainly because while I ran this command I never referenced the actual hostname or username etc. Can anyone provide me with an idea of how I am to use these details if the proxycommand just has %h and %p. Do i replace these values with the host provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you put the snippet you've been given to `~/.ssh/config`, you will just do `ssh hostname`, and the magic will be taken care of by ssh.

Comment: Thanks. So the fact that when i navigate to this folder there is no config and the fact that I am using a different user than my colleague leads me to believe I need to have a user with such priviliges. Will update when i get chatting to him. Thanks.